# crossbrowser - get css color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the background color of an element:

```
var bgcolor = $('.myclass').first().css('background-color')
```

and trying to convert this to hex

```
function rgbhex(color) {
    return "#" + $.map(color.match(/\b(\d+)\b/g), function (digit) {
               return ('0' + parseInt(digit).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join('');
}
```

but the problem is, I am getting in FireFox `"transparent"` for `bgcolor`, where `rgbhex()` is failing with error:

```
TypeError: elems is null
```

but in chrome, I am getting `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` and `rgbhex()` is working for this.

how can I get the css color in crossbrowser format and convert it to hex?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - linked question is for named colours, not whatever the browser returns from js for the background colour

Comment: Right I should mark it as *related* but it is his *actual*problem

Answer (score 0):

Surely you're going to have to handle situations where the colour is set to a none rgba value?

Browsers are never going to handle this sort of thing perfectly consistently so I think the problem is that you're assuming an rbga value everytime, leaving the code brittle. Even if you use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), which will be more consistent in good browsers than `css()` (which just gets the value directly) you'll still want to handle the edge cases.

I'd do this:

```
if ('transparent' === bgcolor) {
  hex = '#000';
} else {
  // work magic here
}
```

But, you're going to hit other examples in other contexts where the browsers are collectively inconsistent, so perhaps a case statement with a default of black, or white, would be a better solution.